# The character [_] is never valid in a domain name

Tags: tomcat

I have an exception that underscore cannot be used in the domain names. I want to know whether this exception is version specific or underscore cannot be given in the domain names. If it is version specific, advice me how to resolve it.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The character [_] is never valid
>   in a domain name.     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser$DomainParseState.next(HttpParser.java:946)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.readHostDomainName(HttpParser.java:842)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:66)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:40)   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.prepareRequest(AjpProcessor.java:934)
>     at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:456)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I found this issue in tomcat version 8.5.32.

Comment: The underscore is indeed not allowed in a domain name. What is your use case? Tomcat 8.5.x has tightened-up the rules for what is acceptable in a `Host` header to limit the attack surface for both Tomcat and applications that expect, you know, standards to actually be followed.

Comment: yes, I accept that standards to be followed, but windows is allowing underscore. then, what is the problem in using the underscore in my Hostname?

Comment: I can write an application that allows you to enter `%$^&` in domain names, too, but it doesn't mean that Tomcat must then go ahead and allow them.

Answer (score 9):

Tomcat 8.5.x and later implement [strict RFC-compliant hostnames as a security precaution](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62371#c14). HTTP RFCs [require host-header validation](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62371#c25) and therefore Tomcat performs that validation.

There are a [trail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc920) of [RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) which require this kind of checking and define what can and cannot be in a hostname.

Your only options are to downgrade Tomcat (not recommended) or fix your hostname to be a valid domain name.

Comment: By looking at the tomcat changelogs (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html) it looks like the exact versions of tomcat 8.5 and 9 with this change are 8.5.31 and 9.0.5. I guess the change is the one going by the description of `Enable strict validation of the provided host name and port for all connectors`

Answer (score 0):

you can use lower version of **SpringBoot：1.4.2.RELEASE**,this version use embed tomcat with version **8.5.6**, this tomcat version is not strict with domain.
I have met the same problem when i use **SpringBoot:1.5.20.RELEASE** which **tomcat version is 8.5.39**,so you can have a try~ use lower version,or modify the tomcat version ,if you use the gradle to compile the project,you can add this code clip to you **build.gradle**

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.tomcat.embed') {
        details.useVersion '8.5.6'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would *strongly* discourage anyone from simply downgrading to "fix" this problem. You'll end up with an underlying system with published security vulnerabilities.